# Date formats for weeks

Tags: mysql, perl, date

I'm having a difficult time, based on the documentation, of figuring out how to equate week numbers between Perl and MySQL.

How would I calculate the same exact week number in both Perl and MySQL based on a unix timestamp in the same time zone?

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(from_unixtime(datefield), '%Y%U') FROM table;
```

and

```
print strftime('%Y%U', localtime($datevar));
```

should produce identical week numbers for any given timestamp.  Ideally I'd like the week number to be something portable, such as [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date).  While the week numbers in my testing seem to match up sometimes, I can't find anything in the documentation for both Perl and MySQL that confirms that the date formatting clearly adheres to the same definition.

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure how you do it in PERL but MySQL has a WEEKOFYEAR() fn http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_weekofyear

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Perl, look into the [DateTime](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DateTime/) module. It supplies a `week()` method, that can return the week number of the year for a given `DateTime` object:

```
($week_year, $week_number) = $dt->week;
```

Note that the year matters, as a date can be in a week for the previous or next year. This is because of the ISO standard for "week", where the first week of the year is the one that contains the fourth day of January. Thus a date like January 1 could be in the final week of the previous year.

To the untrained eye it looks like MySQL's `YEARWEEK()` function could do the same thing, or as [Mikey1980 suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3611563/date-formats-for-weeks/3611721#3611721), try the `WEEKOFYEAR()` function. It looks like `YEARWEEK()` does the same thing, as [its documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_yearweek) says:

> The year in the result may be different from the year in the date argument for the first and the last week of the year.

...but I can't guarantee they do the same thing. :-)

Comment: DateTime's `week` uses the ISO 8601 definition.  To get MySQL to do the same, use mode 3: `YEARWEEK(from_unixtime(datefield), 3)`.

Comment: Note: The POSIX `strftime` function's `%U` does _not_ use the ISO 8601 definition for week number.  POSIX defines the first Sunday in January as the first day of week 1 (with any days before that forming a partial week 0).

Answer (score 2):

For MySQL try this Query:

```
SELECT WEEKOFYEAR(from_unixtime(datefield)) FROM table;
```

Sorry it's only 1/2 the answer your looking for, but I hope it helps!